# React Server Component (RSC) fails in Suspence

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-server-components

I am trying to migrate a React component to a React Server Component
I made it `async` and wrapped it in `<Suspense>`. It actually is resquested by the client, rendered by the server, and sent back as response. But then the client crashes, and the component is not printed...

Working example: [CodeSandbox (RSC rendered, but crashed client side)](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/rsc-rendered-but-crashed-client-side-6kqkh4?file=/app/page.tsx:1,1)

```js
// page.tsx
<Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
    <TestServerComponent>
        {JSON.stringify(content, undefined, 4)}
    </TestServerComponent>
</Suspense>
```

```js
// TestServerComponent.tsx
'use server'
 
export async function TestServerComponent(props?: PropsWithChildren) {
    console.log('TestServerComponent render:', props)
    return (
        <pre>{props?.children}</pre>
    )
}
```

I can see the HTTP request in the browser:

[image]

The log on the server:

```bash
# Server log
TestServerComponent render: { children: '{\n    "test": true\n}' }
```

And even the HTTP response:

```bash
0:["$@1",["development",null]]
1:["$","pre",null,{"children":"{\n    \"test\": true\n}"}]
```

But then I get an error in the client:

```bash
Warning: Cannot update a component (`Router`) while rendering a different component (`proxy`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `proxy`, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render
at proxy
    at Suspense
    at div
    at Page (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./app/page.tsx:15:82)
#   [...]
```

It has to do with updating state while rendering, and I have found several similar issues
But I'm not in this case, or at least not directly. Looks like `Suspense` is messing up somehow ? I can't find any way to get it to work as expected. It doesn't look like this is from my own code...

Did anyone found a way to make this work ?